# Ubuntu 20.04.2 hits black screen after upgrading to Nvidia driver 460

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.2 on with 2x Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080Ti cards. This worked perfectly, until I somehow upgraded to `nvidia-driver-460` through the regular system auto updates.

After grub I'd see the regular booting info, and then the machine just hangs with a black screen...

If I boot into terminal mode, running `nvidia-smi` would also crash the machine... I'd see some PCIe bus error warnings being printed into terminal periodically also...

In terminal mode, I tried to manually purge nvidia drivers and install `nvidia-driver-440`, but `460` ends up being installed instead and I get the same problem.

Anyone has seen this, or has some insight on how I can fix it? Thanks.

System info:

- OS: `Linux 5.8.0-55-generic x86_64`
- Intel Xeon E5-2630
- Asus X99E Workstation motherboard
- 2x Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080Ti

Answer (score 0):

The same issue!

I have one GTX 1650 card and two Dell 4k monitors connected: one is on the DP and the other is on HDMI.
If I leave only one monitor on HDMI the system boots with nvidia-driver-460 but no 4k resolution mode applicable. nvidia-smi shows correct version of driver and HW info.
If monitor is connected to DP - system stops boot and hangs, independent from second monitor is connected to HDMI or not.

Not the first time Ubuntu exposes updates with "pre-installed" issues. Considering completely switch on Mac.

System info:

```
OS: 5.8.0-55-generic #62~20.04.1-Ubuntu

 *-cpu
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-9400F CPU @ 2.90GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: 1
      bus info: cpu@0
      size: 3991MHz
      capacity: 4100MHz
      width: 64 bits

  *-display
      description: VGA compatible controller
      product: TU117 [GeForce GTX 1650]
      vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
      physical id: 0
      bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
      version: a1
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
```

Comment: Seems related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-460/+bug/1919285